# Office 365 video REST api post method getting 403 forbidden error

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-video-portal

I am trying to update a video title using below rest Api but I'm getting 403 forbidden error.

```
https://xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_api/VideoService/Channels('" + channelID + "')/Videos('" + videoID + "')
var JSONObject = JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Publishing.VideoItem' }, 'Title': 'New title'+videoID });
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: sUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSONObject,
        headers: {
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            //"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            //"content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            //"IF-MATCH": "*"
        },
        success: onViewsUpdatesuccess,
        error: onError
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need Azure access token. Which can be obtained as below

```
function GetAzureMediaAccessToken(spVideoUrl) {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);

    executor.executeAsync({

        url: "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/portals/hub/_api/VideoService/GetVideoByUrl('" + spVideoUrl + "')/GetStreamingKeyAccessToken",

        method: "GET",

        headers: {

            "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata"

        },

        success: function(data) {

            deferred.resolve(data);

        },

        error: function(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {

            deferred.reject(data, errorCode, errorMessage);

        }

    });

    return deferred.promise();

}
```

For entire code you can refer below

https://collab365.community/o365-pointpublishingpersonaltopic-blog-site/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the form digest of the video portal first. I found this complete code example that uses the video chunking api

http://siliconreef.co.uk/2018/06/28/o365-video-api-slicing-dicing-uploading/